# Another way of saying "keep strict watch" that you dont do [A], but that you do do [B]

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I am trying to find another way of saying "keep strict watch" that reflects the following ideas:

(1) the dilligence need to avoid the danger of inadvertently persuing (B - an unwise course)
(2) the persistence required to perusue (A - the beneficial course)
(3) the need to constantly be observant so as to perceive and distinguish the differences between the two.
(4) theneed to be resolute in this effort

Comment: Well, You would need to tell them to “monitor constantly but discretely” (.or “...but inobservés”) Maybe there is a neater way, but I cannot think of it.

Comment: To me, what you described sounds very similar in *structure* to the [Serenity Prayer](https://www.beliefnet.com/prayers/protestant/addiction/serenity-prayer.aspx): "*God grant me the serenity to accept the things I cannot change; courage to change the things I can; and wisdom to know the difference.*" I don't think that either thing is amenable to a single-word or short-phrase description. There are simply too many components going on. Even your *keep strict watch* is insufficient.

Comment: Reminds me of [Remember the face of your father](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/170056/what-does-it-mean-to-forget-the-face-of-ones-father) from the Dark Tower

Answer (score -1):

How about "stay the course" or "keep your eyes on the prize"?